# What testing frameworks are used for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

What unit testing frameworks are used for Rails?

I am reading the book (Pragmatic Programmers Agile Dev. with Rails) which shows how to do unit tests in Rails.

The book showed me the default rails testing suite (a subclass of `Test::Unit`). Is this the main testing framework that is used in the Rails community?  I use RSpec when doing regular ruby, and I would like to be able to use it in Rails too (if it's not too much of a hassle)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rspec is widely used in rails, and in conjunction with [Cucumber](http://cukes.info), is one of the most widely used solutions today. note that rails 3 is using rspec 2, so look for [rspec/rails](http://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails). check out the pragprog.com book rspec and cucumber, a great resource written by the core teams. 
http://pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book

Answer (score 18):

There are many tools for testing rails and other webapps from many different aspects. But if you are new to testing **I highly recommend you start with learning Rails' own testing framework** before start using other tools.

Learning, and later mastering, one testing framework makes it easier in the future to understand pros/cons with other framework and make them work in unison.

You could start with testing the following things:

- Unit Testing your Models
- Functional Tests for Your Controllers
- Learning about Fixtures and how to load test data

I have seen many failed testing efforts, but I never saw them fail because they choose the wrong tool/framework. They fail because they don't know how to master the tools they use, and learn enough about the basics about testing.

Read more about Rails testing here.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Answer (score 4):

http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/testing_frameworks.html

Answer (score 2):

I would say rspec is the most widely used.  It's easy to get it up and running, it's expressive and easy to use.  Rails comes with Test::Unit support by default, but I don't see many people using it.  And of course there's a myriad of smaller testing frameworks that a small number of people use.  But it's mostly rspec.

Comment: now that rails 3 is out it is important to note that rails provides test harness agnosticism, allowing you to pick your test solution and enforcing no baked in solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, rspec is used for Rails too. You can find some other examples listed [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#other-testing-approaches) (although I didn't try most of them).