# I'm overwhelmed with the amount of tools used for testing rails apps, where should I start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, rubygems

I've never bothered with testing because my apps where relatively simple and I wanted to focus on learning ruby and rails, and developing functionality. I want some tools/gems that are relatively simple to use. Ideally I want to do:

- Model testing
- Helper testing
- Integration testing (I won't test my views or controllers directly)
- See test coverage
- Automate (run all my tests with one command)

I'm thinking about MiniTest (or RSpec?) for the first two, adding Capybara for integration testing and I have no idea about the last two.

I'm using:

- OSX 10.7.3
- Ruby 1.9.3-p194
- Rails 3.2.3

Thanks!

Comment: You might find SO questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8956816/960195), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3673041/960195), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3564228/960195), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8839091/960195) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finding the right tool for each task I recommend [ruby-toolbox.com](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com) and searching by category, in your case, 'Code Metrics', and 'Continuous Testing'. This way the possible solutions appear ordered by popularity and usage rate in the ruby comunity.

For those specific tasks I use SimpleCov and Guard respectively.

About the tests you mentioned, no offense, but do you know what BDD(Behaviour Driven Development) is? And the difference to TDD(Test Driven Development) ?

If yes I'm sorry, but I mentioned it just in case. If not just make a quick google search and then decide which paradigm of testing do you want, and with which purpose.

I personally try to apply the BDD concept on my projects and I use Cucumber for features, while using RSpec for specs.

By the way, "The RSpec Book" is an excelente book about it and it covers RSpec, Cucumber, Webrat(very similar to capybara, the most popular now)  and Selenium.

Hope this helped, if not too much information...

Answer (score 1):

Start off with model testing.  Its the easiest both to understand and to code.
It'll help you try and focus your business logic in your model and in writing RESTful code that operates through an API.

Then move to controller testing which we be much closer to testing the actual flow of what the end users are really doing.

Next helper testing is usually fairly easy.

Finally you may want to do actual view testing but I would hold off for now.

Definitely go with [rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec) right away and save yourself time switching later.

You can run all tests with one command or run them individually.

As you build up a suite you should look into using [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) for a Continuous Integration testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of my answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673041/what-testing-frameworks-are-used-for-rails/6252982#6252982)

There are many tools for testing rails and other webapps from many different aspects. But if you are new to testing **I highly recommend you start with learning Rails' own testing framework** before start using other tools.

Learning, and later mastering, one testing framework makes it easier in the future to understand pros/cons with other framework and make them work in unison.

You could start with testing the following things:

- Unit Testing your Models
- Functional Tests for Your Controllers
- Learning about Fixtures and how to load test data

I have seen many failed testing efforts, but I never saw them fail because they choose the wrong tool/framework. They fail because they don't know how to master the tools they use, and learn enough about the basics about testing.

Read more about Rails testing here.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Comment: And I personally get embarrassed when people ask me, why did you use TOOLX for this. And my best answer I can give them is 'Because my colleague likes it." :)